# How can I avoid running out of heap memory when processing vast sequences in Clojure?

Tags: memory, clojure, jvm, sequence, heap-memory

I'm trying to generate a sequence which corresponds to a breadth-first search of a very wide, deep tree... and I'm hitting memory problems when I go too far along the sequence. Having asked around on the IRC channel and looked here, the number 1 cause of such problems is inadvertently holding onto the head; but I can't see where I'm doing this.

The code is quite simple; here's a version which displays the problem:

```
(def atoms '(a b c))

(defn get-ch [n] (map #(str n %) atoms)) 

(defn add-ch 
  ([] (apply concat (iterate add-ch atoms))) 
  ([n] (mapcat get-ch n)))

(dorun (take 20000000 (add-ch)))
```

And here's another version (which is the one I started out with before getting help from #clojure), which displays the same issue:

```
(def atoms '(a b c))

(defn get-children [n] (map #(str n %) atoms))

(defn add-layer 
  ([] (add-layer atoms)) 
  ([n] (let [child-nodes (mapcat get-children n) ] 
      (lazy-seq (concat n (add-layer child-nodes))))))

(dorun (take 20000000 (add-layer)))
```

Both give me an "OutOfMemoryError Java heap space". I'm running them from the REPL in Eclipse/CounterClockwise, on a Macbook Air.

I'm pretty new to Clojure, so after beating my head against this for a day I'm hoping that this is something trivial I'm overlooking. I realise I could up my heap-size to make the issue less likely to occur, but the sequences I ultimately want to process are so vast I don't think this is going to help me.

I've tried replacing the "take" (in examples above) with "drop", to avoid keeping hold of the head - it makes no difference.

Comment: what about your JVM memory option? >= Xmx2g?

Comment: That's help make the issue less likely, but it'd still occur further down the line, no?

Answer (score 2):

I missed the dorun.
The problem seems to be with the StringBuilder str.

This works if I replace get-children as below:

```
 (defn get-children [n] (map #(if (seq? n) (conj n %) (conj (list n) %)) atoms))
```

Comment: When the repl tries to print the sequence, it keeps hold of the head. A common idiom would be to doseq on the huge lazy seq and print one element at a time. I have an alternate solution for this which seems to work - the gist being replace str with a conj on a list and then rather than evaluating the (take 200000...) directly, use doseq and print.

Comment: Please ignore my earlier comment - I missed the dorun.  With an alternate implementation of get-children as above which avoids the str ensures that this implementation is lazy all the way through.

Comment: i say delete the wrong stuff.  i'll delete my q and then no-one will know... (thanks for getting tot he bottom of this - interesting problem and still not sure i understand why the fix fixes things)

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I'm afraid - I still get an OutOfMemoryError. I think the problem here is nothing to do with Clojure, actually: it's with the algorithm. I'm maintaining a sequence of entries; every time I take one off, I add its children on - so the sequence grows by 2 entries. Eventually, that has to overflow memory. I suspect your implementation lasts longer by adding to an existing sequence, rather than creating a new string for each entry.

Comment: Tom, at what number do you run out of memory - I tried with 200000000 and I ran out of stack, not heap - i suspect thats because of the recursive call - using recur would solve that as well.